# .NET open existing excel file issues

Tags: .net, excel, com

I am having an issue with trying to open an existing excel file through .NET. I have looked everywhere and tried everything to try and get it working. I can get the file to open ok but it is opening behind all my other windows so i am having to click on the icon in taskbar to be able to see the workbook.

Here is the code i am currently using to open the file.

```
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Test.xlsx")
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    xlApp.Visible = True
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Visible = true is a must, but maybe the application is minimized.
You should try also to set the window state (property) to normal (or even maximized), with

```
xlApp.WindowState = XlNormal
```

(XlNormal is -4143 or  FFFFEFD1, if you haven´t access to the enumerated constants)

Another thing we sometime did, was to bring the window to the front, using the function BringWindowToTop in user32.dll. But you need the window handle of the Excel application